# android datepickerDialog should not accept future dates

Tags: android, datetime

I am using a date picker dialog for selecting the date of birth of the users, so i am able to display the dialog. but the user should not be allowed to increase the year or date or month than present date. How can i do this?

Here is my code:

```
private int mYear;
     private int mMonth;
     private int mDay;
     static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 1;
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.main);   

             Button pickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but);
             pickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                     public void onClick(View v) {
                             showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
                     }
             });
             final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
             mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
             mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
             mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);             
     }
     @Override
     protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
             switch (id) {
             case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                     return new DatePickerDialog(this,
                             mDateSetListener,
                             mYear, mMonth, mDay);
             }
             return null;
     }
     protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
             switch (id) {
             case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                     ((DatePickerDialog) dialog).updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                     break;
             }
     }    

     private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
             new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
             public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                        if (year > mYear)
                        view.updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);

                        if (monthOfYear > mMonth && year == mYear)
                        view.updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);

                        if (dayOfMonth > mDay && year == mYear && monthOfYear == mMonth)
                        view.updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);
             }
     };
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@Override
     protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
             switch (id) {
             case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                     DatePickerDialog _date =  new DatePickerDialog(this,  mDateSetListener,
                             mYear, mMonth, mDay){
                @Override
                public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
                {   
                     if (year > mYear)
                        view.updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);

                        if (monthOfYear > mMonth && year == mYear)
                        view.updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);

                        if (dayOfMonth > mDay && year == mYear && monthOfYear == mMonth)
                        view.updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);

                }
            };
            return _date;
     }
     }
```

you must use the above oncreate dialog for restricting future dates

```
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, 
                int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                      //do your stuff when user clicks on set button in dialog  
        }
    };
```

Comment: user actions disable for the increment of year, month and date if it is showing present date.

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Since API level 11 there is a method for that:
    DatePicker.setMaxDate(long maxDate) 

2. If it has to work in previous versions, use this method:
    public void init(int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth, DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener onDateChangedListener)
```

You could pass your own OnDateChangedListener which "resets" invalid dates to the newest valid one:

```
DatePicker picker = ... 
int year = ... 
int monthOfYear = ... 
int dayOfMonth = ... 
picker.init(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth, new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() { 

    @Override 
    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) { 
        // check if current date is OK 
        boolean dateOk = ... 
        if (!dateOk) { 
            // correct the date, but be sure the corrected date is OK 
            // => otherwise you might get endless recursion 
            year = ... 
            monthOfYear = ... 
            dayOfMonth = ... 
            // update the date widget with the corrected date values 
            view.updateDate(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth); 
        } 
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.DatePicker;

public class MyDatePickerDialog extends DatePickerDialog {

    private CharSequence title;
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
     int maxYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR) -100; // this year ( 2013 ) +100 =2113
    int maxMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int maxDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int minYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int minMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);; // january
    int minDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    /**
     * Instantiates a new my date picker dialog.
     *
     * @param context the context
     * @param callBack the call back
     * @param year the year
     * @param monthOfYear the month of year
     * @param dayOfMonth the day of month
     */
    public MyDatePickerDialog(Context context, OnDateSetListener callBack,
            int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        super(context, callBack, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the permanent title.
     *
     * @param title the new permanent title
     */
    public void setPermanentTitle(CharSequence title) {
        this.title = title;
        setTitle(title);
    }


    @Override
    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        //super.onDateChanged(view, year, month, day);
        disable(view, year, month, day);
        setTitle(title);

    }


    private void disable(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {


                if (year < maxYear)
                view.updateDate(maxYear, maxMonth, maxDay);

                if (monthOfYear < maxMonth && year == maxYear)
                view.updateDate(maxYear, maxMonth, maxDay);

                if (dayOfMonth < maxDay && year == maxYear && monthOfYear == maxMonth)
                view.updateDate(maxYear, maxMonth, maxDay);

                if (year >minYear)
                // view.updateDate(minYear, minDay, minMonth);

                view.updateDate(minYear, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

                if (monthOfYear > minMonth && year == minYear)
                // view.updateDate(minYear, minMonth, minMonth);
                view.updateDate(minYear, minMonth, dayOfMonth);

                if (dayOfMonth > minDay && year == minYear && monthOfYear == minMonth)
                view.updateDate(minYear, minMonth, minDay);
                }


}
```